# JavaFX ListView long press

Tags: java, javafx

In my program I need to make an action when a ListView item is long pressed/click.
But I have not found any working solution, this is why I'm reaching out to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the `ListCell`s returned from the `cellFactory` by adding a `onMousePressed` and a `onMouseReleased` event handler. In the pressed handler store the time and in the released event check, if the time that has ellapsed since pressing the mouse button exceeds a certain duration:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        listView.getItems().add("item " + i);
    }

    final long minDelay = 3 * 1000; // 3 sec min

    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

        private long pressTime;

        {
            setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
                if (!isEmpty()
                        && evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // save time of press start
                }
            });
            setOnMouseReleased(evt -> {
                if (!isEmpty()
                        && evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY
                        && pressTime + minDelay <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    System.out.println("long press on " + getItem()); // do something, if enough time has ellapsed since press
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
        }

    });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

If you instead want to trigger the event before the mouse is released, use a `PauseTransition` to trigger a handler after some delay:

```
final PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));

class FinishedHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    ListCell<String> source;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // do something, if the mouse is pressed for a certain time before releasing it
        System.out.println("long press on " + source.getItem());
    }

}

final FinishedHandler handler = new FinishedHandler();
delay.setOnFinished(handler);

listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

    {
        setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                handler.source = this;
                delay.play();
            }
        });
        setOnMouseReleased(evt -> {
            delay.stop();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item);
    }

});
```